# Uninstall Gnome 3.10 problem

Tags: 13.10

Gnome 3.10 just wont seem to uninstall...

I installed it using the method from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

*(Possibly - I just copied these in from the OP's link - from @Wilf)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-music gnome-maps cheese gnome-documents
```

It also had these uninstall instructions:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

I have tried every solution I stumbled upon. However, parts of it seem to remain no matter what.
ppa-purge cant find any packages to purge etc etc..

Comment: How far did you get in the insta.llation before you removed it ?*(you can check my edit as well)* The `ppa-purge` commands should work, but you can always [check in the software centre](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#A.2BIBw-History.2BIB0_section) to find out what was installed...

Comment: Everything was up and running, however, it froze rather often and i had to restart X, and the stock ubuntu 13.10 gnome got a little messed up.